# Tkinter application is deiconified when starting from fullscreen of another app (MacOS)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, fullscreen

I have a tk instance I want it to remain forever invisible but when the application is started while another application (E.G. VS Code) is fullscreen, it loses its invisible state.  I want the root to be withdrawn forever and never be visible or be able to interact with it (the only real way is to close it through the Dock but that doesn't deiconify so that's fine). How can I make it always stay invisible (not using alpha as you can still close it and mess with it)? To understand the issue run the following in a file with a terminal fullscreen:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

[Video of issue.](https://vimeo.com/821029983?share=copy)

Comment: See [ask]. It's unclear. What is "the main app"? How do the apps(the Tkinter app, "another app" and "the main app") interacts? You said multiple desktops. What is the detailed UX scenario involving multiple desktops?

Comment: @relent95 I updated the question to better explain the situation. I was under the impression that the video of VS Code in fullscreen and then it moving over and deiconifying the window would be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: It's still unclear. Are you asking on how to create an invisible window? Then how is that related to the fullscreen mode?

Comment: I want it to remain forever invisible but when the application is opened in fullscreen, it loses its invisible state.

Comment: Now that makes sense. It's not related to the fullscreen mode or multiple desktops(workspaces). Try to run your Python module from the terminal application while not in the full screen mode, and click the icon in Dock. It will show the Tkinter window. If you edit the question, I'll answer.

Comment: It doesn't show the window, as I would hope. When run in fullscreen, it does show it, unlike what I want. In other words: fullscreen breaks deiconify.

Comment: It wasn't produced because I tested in the interactive mode. I'll answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There occur two problems when the Tkinter root window is created and withdrawn immediately, while another application is running in full screen mode.

1. The Tkinter window appears in another desktop(workspace) and the current desktop is changed into that desktop.
2. The Tkinter window does not disappear despite the `withdraw()` was called.

This seems to be a bug in Tcl/Tk. But I don't expect it will be fixed soon, because this requires a new functionality to create a main window in an unmapped state and map it manually at later, but this use case is very rare.

You can't fix the first problem. But you can remedy the second problem, by using a transparent window, like the following example.

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.config(background = 'systemTransparent')
root.wm_overrideredirect(True)
root.wm_attributes('-transparent', True)
root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Also, if you need only Tcl functionality and don't need a Tk functionality, you can initialize the root interpreter like this.

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk(useTk=False)
...
```